# select inside CLOB and get what it cotains

Tags: oracle

I am not sure if this is duplicated ,I havent find it in the search.

I have a table called *mytable* that has column *STORY* the type of this column is **CLOB**

> mytable
>
> The elder tree
>   Soldiers 
>   Going for a hunt
>   The blue moon

If i write :

> select story from mytable

I will have the result:

> Mytable
>   
>   1-clob
>   2-clob
>   3-clob
>   4-clob

What I want what inside CLOB , can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dbms_lob.substr( clob, bytes, startbyte );
```

but in sql you can retrieve only 4000 bytes into varchar

Comment: If I want to apply it on my example then :
dbms_lob.substr( story, 4000, 1 ); ?

Comment: If I want to put it in a querry and sepcify columns and conditions how can i acceive that ? and how to specify the table name ?

Comment: select dbms_lob.substr( clob, bytes, startbyte ) as story from mytable 
 
if you want to do somthing with with the converted story column you can wrap the query with another query  select * from (select dbms_lob.substr( clob, bytes, startbyte ) as story from mytable ) Q where Q.story = 'something'